# How to complete missing values in column and row of a dataframe based on vector as source

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have the following data frame:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

df <- tibble(
  source = c("a", "b", "b"),
  target = c("a", "b", "c"),
  score = c(10, 5, 3) ) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = target, values_from = score) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  column_to_rownames(var = "source")


df
```

It looks like this

```
  a  b  c
a 10 NA NA
b NA  5  3
```

Now the column and row names are incomplete. The complete names is 
given in this vector:

```
master_source_target <- c("a", "b","c","d")
```

I want to complete in the column and row of the data frame based on that vector so that the end
it will look like this:

```
   a  b  c  d
a 10 NA NA  NA
b NA  5  3  NA
c NA  NA NA NA
d NA  NA NA NA
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier with a `matrix` of `NA`s and then do the assignment based on the dimnames of 'df'

```
new <- matrix(NA, length(master_source_target), 
    length(master_source_target), 
       dimnames = list(master_source_target, master_source_target))
new[row.names(df), colnames(df)] <- unlist(df)
new
#   a  b  c  d
#a 10 NA NA NA
#b NA  5  3 NA
#c NA NA NA NA
#d NA NA NA NA
```

---

As the OP used `tibble`, we can also make use of tidyverse approachess

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   rownames_to_column('rn') %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -rn, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
   complete(rn = master_source_target, name = master_source_target) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>% 
   column_to_rownames('rn')
```

---

Or with `crossing` and a join

```
crossing(Var1 = master_source_target, Var2 = master_source_target) %>% 
   left_join(as.data.frame.table(as.matrix(df))) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = Var2, values_from = Freq) %>%
   column_to_rownames('Var1')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add missing column names first and then `rbind` missing rows with `NA`.

```
df[setdiff(master_source_target, names(df))] <- NA
rbind(df,matrix(NA, nrow = length(master_source_target) - nrow(df), ncol = ncol(df),
        dimnames = list(setdiff(master_source_target, rownames(df)), names(df))))

#   a  b  c  d
#a 10 NA NA NA
#b NA  5  3 NA
#c NA NA NA NA
#d NA NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a single step:

```
df[setdiff(master_source_target, rownames(df)), master_source_target] <- NA

df
   a  b  c  d
a 10 NA NA NA
b NA  5  3 NA
c NA NA NA NA
d NA NA NA NA
```